# how to fix response.json() no data available error?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

Earlier today I was trying to web scrape some climate data from here: https://www.weather.gov/wrh/Climate?wfo=sew. I have since found a better way to get the data I need, but I'm still confused about the code issue.

I'm new to web scraping but have the following code. The session.post() request returns a status code 200, which I assume means the data was found, but the request.json() gives "{'error': 'no data available'}". Does anyone know why this might be?

```
s = requests.session()
url_search = 'https://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

data = {"elems":[{"name":"maxt","add":"t"},{"name":"mint","add":"t"},{"name":"avgt","add":"t"},{"name":"avgt","normal":"departure91","add":"t"},{"name":"hdd","add":"t"},{"name":"cdd","add":"t"},{"name":"pcpn","add":"t"},{"name":"snow","add":"t"},{"name":"snwd","add":"t"}],"sid":"KRNT+5","sDate":"2022-12-01","eDate":"2022-12-31"}

req = s.post(url_search, headers = headers, json = data)
j = req.json()
```

Comment: It probably just means that the criteria you've specified in the JSON payload don't match anything

Comment: You don't fix it, it's a normal response when there's nothing that matches the criteria. You should just check for it: `if 'error' in j:`

Comment: No, it's not @Barmar. If you go to https://www.weather.gov/wrh/Climate?wfo=sew, check XHR post calls, and try to use the same payload (params) as in there, you will still get an error.

Comment: But you're not querying weather.gov, you're querying data.tcc-acis.org.

Comment: Yes, but weather.gov is pulling data from tcc-arcgis @Barmar. Nonetheless, Andrej saved the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass data in `data=` parameter, not in `json=` parameter. Also, try to remove the `+` part from the `"sid"` parameter:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData"

payload = {
    "params": '{"elems":[{"name":"maxt","add":"t"},{"name":"mint","add":"t"},{"name":"avgt","add":"t"},{"name":"avgt","normal":"departure91","add":"t"},{"name":"hdd","add":"t"},{"name":"cdd","add":"t"},{"name":"pcpn","add":"t"},{"name":"snow","add":"t"},{"name":"snwd","add":"t"}],"sid":"OLMthr","sDate":"2022-12-01","eDate":"2022-12-31"}',
    "output": "json",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "meta": {"state": "WA", "sids": ["OLMthr 9"], "uid": 32815, "name": "Olympia Area"},
    "data": [
        [
            "2022-12-01",
            ["36", 24],
            ["22", 24],
            ["29.0", 24],
            ["-11.2", 24],
            ["36", 24],
            ["0", 24],
            ["0.07", 24],
            ["M", -1],
            ["M", -1],
        ],
        [
            "2022-12-02",
            ["41", 24],
            ["27", 24],
            ["34.0", 24],
            ["-6.0", 24],
            ["31", 24],
            ["0", 24],
            ["0.43", 24],
            ["M", -1],
            ["M", -1],
        ],

...and so on.
```

Comment: OP should use `"sid":"KRNT 5"` to get the relevant data. +1.